# How to make button with text+icon the same size as button with text only

Tags: android

I have a set of buttons in a table each with some text. I now wish to have some of the buttons include a drawable icon on top (obviously with smaller text) without disrupting the size of the buttons. Is there a standard way of achieving this?

Note: I wish to do this all programmatically rather than via an xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher), null, null);
b.setText("Button");
```

Try this and let me know what happen..

Comment: I did try that code and the combined text+icon buttons are much taller than the text only buttons.

Comment: The code is for example, just define layout params for button and then use it.

Comment: Oops, I had android:layout_height="wrap_content" - if I change this to match parent then that fixes it.